# UIWebView in UITableView reloads everytime I scroll. How do I prevent it from reloading?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview, youtube-api

Currently I have a `UITableView` that has a `UIWebView` in every `cell`. Each `UIWebView` is loading a unique embedded YouTube video. Is there a way to keep the `UIWebView` from reloading when scrolling. It looks cheaply developed when it scrolls on screen and is a white rectangle to loading a video thumbnail. I was looking into `UIWebView` caching but I don't know how I would go about caching the `WebView` to reuse it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this differently, just define new table view cell for that particular index like

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil] retain];
```

see if that makes a difference you desire

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the `UITableViewCell` somewhere (an array in your `UITableViewController`, for example), and return the existing `cell` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call, instead of `de-queueing` a new `cell`.