# UIWebView inside UITableViewCell load content everytime I scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I am using `UIWebView` to load Youtube video inside `UITableView`. Everything works fine except it **loads everytime** I scroll tableview. I have read this question ([UIWebView in UITableView reloads everytime I scroll. How do I prevent it from reloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203101/uiwebview-in-uitableview-reloads-everytime-i-scroll-how-do-i-prevent-it-from-re)) but not solved yet.

My code:

```
NSString *videoUrl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\"",     videoId];
            NSString *htmlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe width=\"273\" height=\"152\" %@ frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", videoUrl];
            NSLog(@"%@", htmlString);
            cell.myWebview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
            cell.myWebview.scrollView.bounces = NO;
            [cell.myWebview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.myWebview];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
[cell.myWebview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];
```

everytime, that´s why. Maybe you can load the webviews in another place and then in the cellForRowIndexPath method just assing it like:

```
cell.myWeview = "....already loaded webview"
```

Comment: Could you give me the code? Sorry I still don't understand :).